# Migration notification for an answer that's not mine

Tags: support, migration, notification-bar, migrated-questions

I logged into SO to the following banner:

[image]

Here's the problem: This [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37107/error-extra-alignment-tab-has-been-changed-to-cr#3956983) has only one answer, and it's not mine, nor are there any deleted answers. I never answer TeX questions, as I have only limited experience with LaTeX, so I can confidently assert that I have NEVER added an answer to this question, on SO or otherwise. In addition, my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393099/zeke) still has 23 answers listed, the same number it had yesterday and none of them have this title.

Does anyone have any idea as to why I am getting this notification?

Answer (score 8):

You actually did have an answer, though it really should have been a comment on the question, not posted as an answer.  Two mods were looking at the post at the same time.  One migrated the question and at the same time, another mod deleted your answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for checking that out. I have no recollection of answering this, so I apologize for wasting everyone's time. Was the answer already deleted? I'm wondering why my answer count in my profile overview didn't decrease.

Comment: Your answer was deleted at the same time another mod migrated.  It wasn't really an answer, just a comment pointing someone to the TeX site posted over a year ago.